# 'There is no source code available for the current location.' when throwing an exception in C++ Visual Studio

Tags: c++, exception, visual-c++

I have a problem in catching an exception. I am trying to rethrow an exception and I get a message:

> There is no source code available for the current location.

The code is very simple:

```
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

try {
    throw exception("Asas");
}
catch (const exception& e) {
   cout<< "Error msg" << e.what() << endl;
   throw; //This the error message I get from the IDE.
}
```

It also repeats if I try to throw a string message and try to rethrow it.

Comment: In what context do you get the message from the IDE? When debugging?

Comment: And what was your expected behavior?

Comment: That the function that called this function would catch the exception.

Comment: If I add to the throw also the e it seems to work OK.

Comment: @roman, but throw e is not like throw, as the last does not create another object like the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is so misleading, it's very hard to give you back anything but more questions.

You write you get this message when you're trying to rethrow, but it's very unclear what you mean: Is this a compiler error, a run-time error, or something you get while you're debugging? If the latter (which I assume), why are you debugging? Isn't the thrown exception caught? If so, what's the code that attempts to catch it?

I suggest you change your question to show a small, but complete piece of code (ideally self-contained and compilable) plus a exact description of `A)` what happens and `B)` what you think *should* happen instead.

Meanwhile, all I can say is that the error message you quote might mean that you are running/debugging something that isn't compiled from the code you look at. But that#s about as vague as your question...

Comment: I am sorry from the misleading.
I get it when debugging. 
Yes you are right I tried to run it without debug in it was ok. 
Why is the difference ? and how can I debug my application ?

Comment: @Roman: I still have no idea what exactly you're doing, what happens, and what you expect to happen instead. Go and edit your question according to my suggestions. Maybe then someone will understand what's happening. As it is, I'm not even sure what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are stepping into the re-throw, and you probably don't have source code for the part of the code you stepped into. You will get those messages when the IDE can't find source code for the current line of code.

Comment: but this is the same application. This is not a DLL or any kind of library.

Comment: @leiz, the problem is in the throw;

Comment: @Ahmed, that is what I said -- he is stepping into rethrow or something